# asp.net store sum of the score in the database when an user is the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I got the following sql query in my aspx page to update my database in phpmyadmin. My software is visual web developer 2010.

```
  cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE (userscore) SET score = @score WHERE username = @username";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", userscore);
            var numRowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (numRowsAffected == 0)
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO userscore (username, score)VALUES(@username,   @score)";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

This query adds an username plus is score in the database, when the specific username isn't in the database yet. That's what I want. But when for example the username admin is in the datbase with a score of -1 (in my application you can vote +1 or -1) and he gets another vote of +1, I want to store the sum the values (in this case -1 plus +1 = 0)in the database as the new score, and delete the old value, which in this example is -1.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just wrap your "upsert" code into the stored procedure, and pass the userid and the score increment/decremnt.

Your current code does not update the score, but simply overwrites it with whatever you pass into it

```
create proc SetUserScore
@UserName nvarchar(100),
@ScoreChange int
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM userscore WHERE username = @UserName)
    BEGIN
      UPDATE userscore 
      SET score = score + @ScoreChange
      WHERE username = @UserName
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO userscore (username, score)VALUES(@username,   @score)
    END

END
```

Comment: Thnx fo the reply but where do I have to place this stored procedure in my aspx file?

Comment: When I type this command in the mysql command line it says: ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected?

Comment: I didn't realize you're using MySQL, tag your question as such please. My code would create a stored procedure in SQL Server; not sure how you do it in MySQL

Comment: google can! http://ruionwriting.net/2010/10/mysql-vs-mssql-upsert-stored-procedure/